# How to write test cases using junit for JPA REST API?

Tags: junit, dbunit

I want to write junit test cases for my RESTful API webservices to check the response and expected response from DB.
The basic flow here is REST file (calls) -> BusinessLogic (fetches result from DB) -> REST file (return)

Here is my REST file:

```
@Path("add")
@Stateless
public class AddingREST {

@Inject
private AddBO addBO;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("success/{n1}/{n2}")
public List addREST(@PathParam("id") int n1, @PathParam("id") int n2) {
    return addBO.add(n1, n2);
}
```

}

And here is the Business Logic file:

```
@Stateless
public class AddBO {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "WebApplicationPU")
private EntityManager entityManager;

public List add(int n1, int n2) {
    int n3 = entityManager.createNamedQuery("SELECT no from no_table").getResultList();
    List numbers = new ArrayList<int>();
    numbers.add(n1);
    numbers.add(n2);
    numbers.add(n3);
    numbers.add(n1+n2+n3);
    return numbers;
}
```

}

The question here is how to provide the value fetched from DB for n3 in the test case as the actual code is in different database which I do not want to clean. So basically, the test case will run on a different empty database and while running the database I have to insert the data and clean the database after the test case executes.

How do I proceed with this? Should I use DBUnit for inserting and cleaning the data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, dbUnit works well for database prepping with JPA.